# Why does os.path.isabs() not give the result that I expect

Tags: python, path

```
print(str(os.path.isabs("c:///\\\\xmls\\hello.txt")))
```

This source code returns `True`.

Why is that?

How can `c:///\\\\xmls\\hello.txt` possibly be a valid path?

Comment: Looks like ```isabs()``` only checks if it's an absolute path or not and doesn't check if it's a valid path? https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html

Comment: For future reference, please post a [mre] when asking questions here. In this case what you want know has nothing to do with classes or `classmethod`s, so all the irrelevant stuff could and should have been eliminated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [official](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/os.path.html#os.path.isabs) doc:

```
Return True if path is an absolute pathname. 
On Unix, that means it begins with a slash, 
on Windows that it begins with a (back)slash after chopping off a potential drive letter.
```

In other words, even this code print `True`

```py
os.path.isabs("/hello world")
```

because it starts with a `/`